# Load image into memory immediately

Tags: wpf, memory, rendering, tiff, frames

I need to open all frames from Tiff image in WPF into memory and then delete the source. And after that I eventually need to render that image (resized according to window size). My solution is quite slow and I cannot delete file source before the first require. Any best practices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`

This option can be used with the `BitmapImage.CacheOption` property or as an argument to `BitmapDecoder.Create()`  If you want to access multiple frames once the images is loaded you'll have to use `BitmapDecoder.Create`.  In either case the file will be loaded fully and closed.

See also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661532/deleting-a-windows-background-image-wpf)

**Update**

The following code works perfectly for loading in all the frames of an image and deleting the file:

```
var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(imageFileName), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
List<BitmapFrame> images = decoder.Frames.ToList();
File.Delete(imageFileName);
```

You can also access decoder.Frames after the file is deleted, of course.

This variant also works if you prefer to open the stream yourself:

```
List<BitmapFrame> images;
using(var stream = File.OpenRead(imageFileName))
{
  var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
  images = decoder.Frames.ToList();
}
File.Delete(imageFileName);
```

In either case it is more efficient than creating a `MemoryStream` because a `MemoryStream` keeps two copies of the data in memory at once:  The decoded copy and the undecoded copy.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I access to multiple frames of image in BitmapImage object?

Comment: You can use BitmapDecoder.Create(), then you can get all the frames.  I added a paragraph to my answer to explain this.

Comment: I currently do this, I just don't know how can I convert BitmapFrame to BitmapImage. After I copy all frames to List<BitmapFrame> I cannot delete image file. I need just delete image file right after all frames are loaded into memory.

Comment: I think you must have made some mistake.  `BitmapCacheOption.Onload` really does load all the data and close the source file when used with `BitmapDecoder.Create()`.  Perhaps you passed it a `Stream` and forgot to close the stream after the call returned?  Perhaps you forgot to add the `OnLoad` option in you test?  Perhaps you used `new` instead of the `.Create()` method?  I'll update my answer with some code the really does work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have to use *MemoryStream*:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(image));
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
List<BitmapFrame> images = new List<BitmapFrame>();
foreach (BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames) images.Add(frame);
```

Comment: This is inefficient because it keeps two copies of the file in memory at the same time:  The MemoryStream and the data in the BitmapFrames.  My answer achieves the same result more efficiently, and it *really* does work.